# How to solve Custom-Calendar-View Library issue for wrong selected current date?

Tags: android, android-calendar

if you are using [Custom-Calendar-View](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/) Library in your android application
you wil face this [issue](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/issues/6)
Same position of current date in previous month also set selected while move to previous month.

and after long code tracing I solved it.. find the solution below its very simple 
just moving a line to another place.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question...can you rephrase it to what you would have searched for if you didn't know the answer?

Comment: @Chris yes its Q&A for Custom-Calendar-View Library issue. and I solved the issue ... find below the answer

Comment: I understand what you intend it to be - my recommendation to make it better is to phrase it as a question people might ask so it's more easily searchable and helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the folowing changes in setDaysInCalendar() method in class CustomCalendarView.java

```
private void setDaysInCalendar() {
```

...

**Move this line**

```
   //Set the current day color
   markDayAsCurrentDay(startCalendar);
```

**TO**

```
 if (isSameMonth(calendar, startCalendar)) {
                dayOfMonthContainer.setOnClickListener(onDayOfMonthClickListener);
                dayView.setBackgroundColor(calendarBackgroundColor);
                dayView.setTextColor(dayOfWeekTextColor);

       // to here
      //Set the current day color
       markDayAsCurrentDay(startCalendar);

    } else {
                dayView.setBackgroundColor(disabledDayBackgroundColor);
                dayView.setTextColor(disabledDayTextColor);

                if (!isOverflowDateVisible())
                    dayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else if (i >= 36 && ((float) monthEndIndex / 7.0f) >= 1) {
                    dayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
```

...